# AngularJS - return value of a promise ID field in a factory

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, promise

I am recovering all data in `allEnquetes`. I just find the requested this list, but an error occurs because the `allEnquetes` returns a promise.

```
.factory('enquetesAPI', function($http,myConfig){

  return {  
      allEnquete: function(){
      return $http.get(myConfig.remote + '/lists.asp?acao=list-enquete&codadmin='+myConfig.codadmin);

      },

      getEnquete: function(enqueteId) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.allEnquete().length; i++) {        
          if (this.allEnquete()[i].codigo === parseInt(enqueteId)) {
            return this.allEnquete()[i];
          }
        }
        return this.allEnquete()      
      }
  };

})
```

[This is the result when I console.log ( this.allEnquete )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ipx2S.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

allEnquetes returns a promise so you just can't loop through that. Check below code. I have not tested it. but this should give you some idea on how you should ideally be doing this.

```
.factory('enquetesAPI', function($http, $q, myConfig){

  return {  
      allEnquete: function(){
       console.log('called');
        return $http.get(myConfig.remote + '/lists.asp?acao=list-enquete&codadmin='+myConfig.codadmin);

      },

      getEnquete: function(enqueteId) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        this.allEnquete().then(function(enquetes){
          var returnVal = enquetes;
          for (var i = 0; i < enquetes.length; i++) {  
            if (this.allEnquete()[i].codigo === parseInt(enqueteId)){
              returnVal = enquetes[i];
            }
          }
          deferred.resolve(returnVal);
        }, function(errorResponse){
          deferred.reject(errorResponse);
        });

        return deferred.promise;  
      }
  };

});
```

and this is how you should be using your service.

```
enquetesAPI.getEnquete(id).then(enquetes){
  // do whatever you need to do
}
```

Comment: Errors: TypeError: this.allEnquete is not a function

Comment: sorry for that. that was untested code. I made the corrections. This should work now.